# Fail to link to standard library of Ocaml-java (or Cafesterol)

Tags: jar, compilation, ocaml, standard-library

I am a new user of Ocaml-java (or Cafesterol) which compiles primtive Ocaml program to executable jar that is allowed run on JVM. However when I try to compile a test program into executable jar I got error info as follow:

```
>java -jar ~/ocaml-project/ocamljava-bin-1.4/bin/ocamljava.jar -standalone regexdna.ml -o         regexdna.jar
File "regexdna.ml", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
     Str referenced from regexdna.cmj
     Unix referenced from regexdna.cmj
```

It seems module Str and Unix is missing from Ocaml-java. However, str.jar and unix.jar do exist under ~/ocaml-project/ocamljava-bin-1.4/lib/others/ when I install Ocaml-java, and within these jars we do have Str.class and Unix.class. (I suppose this directory is on the path of the standard library of Ocaml-java, so it should be included in default search path)

Can any Ocaml-java user tell me how Ocaml-java search for dependency libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Xavier Clerc on this :

> Well it should work, but you have to pass explicitly the referenced
>   library (just as in vanilla OCaml). Leading in your case to:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar ~/opt/ocamljava-2.0-early-access9/lib/ocamljava.jar str.cmja regexdna.ml
```

Note that I am using the latest ocamljava preview.